# Error: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a `js` file which has a function.
When I call that function on `$(document).ready;` it is not working.

I checked through firebug, It is calling the function but not going into the function.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function toggelEventButtons() {
    var invoiceVal = $('#Invoice_Id').val(); //It is a textbox Id of aspx Page.

    alert(invoiceVal);

    if (invoiceVal > 0) {
        $('#addEventInvoiceDetail').hide();
        $('#editEventInvoiceDetail').show();
    } else {
        $('#addEventInvoiceDetail').show();
        $('#editEventInvoiceDetail').hide();
    }
}
```

I call the function from an `aspx` page like this:

```
$(document).ready(toggelEventButtons);
```

Comment: Is the function definition at toplevel, or inside another function?

Comment: It is independent. Not inside another function.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is calling function but not going into the function"?

Comment: Make sure that you included file with function before calling $(document).ready().

Comment: that function is on other js script? did you forget to include it?

Comment: I mean when I debug through firebug, It goes on function toggelEventButtons() { but not execute its statements.

Comment: what console error did you get?

Comment: @ArtemVyshniakov, Ya I have included file after $(document).ready(). Thanks. It is working now. You can post your answer. So I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you included file with a function before calling `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Incidentally, since this was the problem, it means that the solution `$(function() { toggelEventButtons(); });` *would* in fact have helped. It would not, perhaps, have been the neatest solution to the problem, though :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure the functions are on the same scope.
you can also try this syntax

```
$(document).ready(function(){ toggelEventButtons() });
```